# Drag and Drop between Windows and Java Web Application

Tags: java, windows, web, drag-and-drop

I need to add drag-and-drop functionality to a Java web application, specifically to drag files from the desktop into the web application. A co-worker suggested using the built-in functionality of HTML5 but that seems to be only applicable for dragging elements within the browser window. What do I need to do in my situation?

Comment: Did you try?   
    <input type="file" id="fileinput" multiple="multiple" />

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of HTML5 drag&drop with file upload using ajax :

https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/drag-and-drop-uploader/

Comment: Thanks, @user2447161; I think I'm going the jQuery route, but I'll keep that in mind...

Answer (score 0):

What do you intend using the drag and drop functionality for. If it is for file upload, you can make use of JQuery plugins for this. A very good one is using **[Dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)**.

Comment: Thanks, @David Adelekan. I found a drag-and-drop jQuery example online that seems like it will do what I want to do, so I'm working through it...